# Text to speech erratic after android 4.3 update

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, text-to-speech, ankidroid

I use the app [AnkiDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ankidroid-flashcards/com.ichi2.anki) on my HTC One to learn Italian. It has a text to speech option which, when enabled, reads the text on the flashcards aloud. However, after updating to Android 4.3, this function has become extremely erratic - only 1 of every 20/30 cards is read out (it worked perfectly before the update).

I have also recently bought a Google nexus 7, running Android 4.4.2, and it also has the same issue. Does anybody have any ideas about why this is happening and if possible how I could resolve this?

Comment: This might be an issue for the app developers to address. Have you considered reporting it on the [AnkiDroid Issues Page](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/list)?

Comment: I did report it there but the developers suggested to ask here as it may be something to do with the android update. I have now found a tts engine that is working more reliably, though not perfectly, but I'm pleased. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I released AnkiDroid 2.0.3 yesterday, it fixes the TTS bug described at https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=1892

Does 2.0.3 fix the problem you described in your question?

Before 2.0.3 the TTS part of AnkiDroid had not changed in a long time, so it must be that TTS changed in Android 4.3.

If anybody has some info about what changed in Android 4.3's TTS it would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: The update may well have helped because I have just downloaded Svox Classic and tts seems to work reasonably reliably now. It does miss out the odd word - probably 1 in 8 but I'm really pleased the function is working on the whole once again! Does anyone have any experience with Acapela's compatibility with Ankidroid? Would love some feedback before I buy! I was using Ivona before (which I really like and also happens to be free!) however that, as well as Google's own tts engine, still has major problems for me. Maybe it's an issue to raise with Ivona now. Thanks a lot for your help!